# Image vertical align middle fix code

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I want to fit image into vertical align but I still can't solve this. I have this code which does not work properly:

CSS:

```
#bigpic {
    width: 248px;
    height: 315px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.helper {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#bigpic img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 248px;
    max-height: 315px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="bigpic">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200" />
</div>
```

I just don't see any problem why doesn't it work. Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/3X7rg/. Answer into jsfiddle would be the best. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `line-height: 315px` demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3X7rg/2/

```
#bigpic {
    width: 248px;
    height: 315px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 315px; /*must equal must be equal to height of the div*/
}
```

Comment: Remember the line height must be equal to height of the div. or else it wont work

Answer (score 1):

You can play with your position and percentage.
http://jsfiddle.net/3X7rg/10/

```
#bigpic {
position: absolute;
float: left;
left: 200px;
width: 248px;
height: 315px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#bigpic img {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it. I prefer this method because it allows *variable height* of the div as well as image. So i don't have to manually set the **height**.

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W22DC/68/)

This is achieved using ***table-cell & vertical-align attributes*** in CSS

```
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Agree @AnaMaria. But don't you think that this is a typical table-method used at the time when the great `<table>, <tr>, <td>s` were used for website layout? As in tableless designing, `inline-block` is a method which should ideally be used to achieve this kind of effect?

Comment: @Nathan lee, Agreed. Just trying to throw up different solutions to one problem.

Comment: @NathanLee, By the way my former company i worked for still uses td's and tr.. They suck :)

Comment: That is perfectly fine :) - @AnaMaria. I was curious to get that tabless things coming up.

Comment: Well.. As a matter of fact, it is still considered pretty safe and traditional method of achieving things without learning up too much when you have the WYSIWYG editors design view to get the job done pretty fast without any major browser issues. But it is the time to move on and if not today, but in a very near future, they have to learn the new things. - @AnaMaria. Even at my former company, they used tables :)

Comment: @NathanLee, just hate my former employers so i take every opportunity to vent my frustration at them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34975/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-anamaria)